# Unexpected insertion behavior of captured text in `sed` and `awk` on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, sed, osx-mavericks

I am trying to repeat the words in a dictionary file, where each word is originally mentioned on a line of its own.

I tried doing so using the `sed` and the `awk` commands.

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1\1/g' dict.txt
```

It seems that the captured text is inserted, but without changing the cursor position, so the output remains unchanged:

> ... zionist   zionists   zip   zipped   zipper   zippers   zipping   zippy ...

On the other hand, attempting to replace with `\1AAA\1` results in:

> ... AAAzionist   AAAzionists   AAAzip   AAAzipped   AAAzipper   AAAzippers   AAAzipping   AAAzippy ...

Which, to me, is unexpected.

I also tried using the `awk` command, in few different ways as follows:

```
awk '{ print $1, $1 }' dict.txt
```

or:

```
awk '{ print "%s %s", $1, $1 }' dict.txt
```

where in the latter case, I could finally see replication, but at unexpected cursor positions, occasionally resulting in the repeated word overlapping with the previous one:

```
zoologistogist
zoologistsgists
zoologyology
zoom zoom
zoomedoomed
zoomingoming
```

Kind of frustrating because I can't make sense of it. Can you help me understand?

Comment: Also note that you can sed 's/^.*$/& &/' instead of making an explicit capture. (I still include the BOL/EOL anchors because .* does not actually match everything on a line if you have encoding errors).

Comment: @o11c Thank you. I realized I could accomplish the entire task I wanted using `awk` programming alone, without designing a complicated pipe command. I was trying to sort the words in the English language according to their "vowel content", and maybe make a list of some of the unusual, most-vowely words in the English language for my students (as a joint project between computer and English). The code I came up with eventually was `awk '{ word = $1; gsub(/[^aeiouy]+/, ""); vowels = $1; printf "%3d%% %s\n", length(vowels)/length(word)*100, word }' dict.txt | sort -n | tail -100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to presence of `\r` before EOL in your file which is result of file being edited in a Windows editor.

Use [`dos2unix`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) to convert it:

If `dos2unix` isn't available then use this `sed` to remove `\r` before trying your awk/sed commands:

```
sed -i.bak $'s/\r$//' file
```

Comment: Okay help me a bit further, how can I replace with the repeated words separated by a tab?

Comment: What do you want to replace with?

Comment: @OrwaDiraneyya : You can do the repeated words separated by a tab using `sed 's/^.*$/&\t&/'`. Note that you don't need the `g` parameter of sed here because you're only performing one substitution per line. FWIW, sometimes lines have trailing spaces, which can also cause problems (as well as wasting space when they aren't explicitly wanted). So here's a variant anubhava's command which removes all whitespace from the ends of lines: regular space, tab, vertical tab, formfeed, and carriage return: `sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//'`. However `[:space:]` _won't_ match non-breaking space, `\xa0`.

Comment: Actually, I ended up opening the text file in TextEdit in Mac OS X and saving it again. Since all the variations I tried of the command left some  of the lines in a faulty state. I am not sure why. Now it is working fine. The reason I wanted to add tabs was because I thought it is the right field delimiter for using `awk`, later I discovered a space was sufficient to access one word using $1 and the other using $2 in `awk`. Thank you all, @anubhava and @PM2Ring, you have been very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it all worked out. Yes any whitespace is good enough as default field separator in awk.